# Can I write a query has a conditional table selection

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have 2 tables with identical structure and based on a variable I want to choose which table to select on with out having to write 2 queries in my procedure.

Is this possible?

I tried

```
declare @table int
set @table = 1 

Select orderID, Quantity 
from case when @table = 1 then tblOrders else tblSubscriptionOrders end
where filled = 0
```

But that did not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to use dynamic SQL for this (assuming you want to scale it to more than just 2 tables), which would work but is suboptimal as SQL will not generate statistics for it and have a harder time optimizing the query.

```
declare @table sysname
declare @SQL varchar(1000)

set @table = 'MyTable'
SET @SQL='SELECT orderID, Quantity FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + ' WHERE filled=0'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

or, in a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_ConditionalSelect @table sysname
as

declare @SQL varchar(1000)

set @table = 'MyTable'
SET @SQL='SELECT orderID, Quantity FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + ' WHERE filled=0'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing a sp for a one time execution though that appears to be the solution I amgoing to have to do because the end result is more complicated than the easy sample I put up.

Answer (score 6):

If it's just two tables you could do:

```
Declare @table = 1

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE <stuff>
AND @Table = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Table2
WHERE <stuff>
AND @Table = 2
```

The filter on `@table` will result in only one of the two halves showing data.

Comment: +1 not tested but I assume this would be the fastest solution yet presented.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use Dynamic SQL but if performance isn't an immediate issue, much simpler is to just `UNION` the tables and add a dummy `[table]` column to select from.

```
SELECT orderID, Quantity
FROM   (
  SELECT [table] = 1, orderID, Quantity
  FROM   tblOrders
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [table] = 2, orderID, Quantity
  FROM   tblSubscriptionOrders
  ) t
WHERE t.Table = @table
```