# SQL Server : select from tableA OR tableB OR Both

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to select from `table A`, `table B` or both tables in SQL Server? As much as posible, I don't want to use dynamic SQL. I've seen this in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533539/can-i-write-a-query-that-with-a-conditional-table-selection) but it only selects on 1 table.

```
Declare @table = 1

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE <stuff>
AND @Table = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Table2
WHERE <stuff>
AND @Table = 2
```

Comment: Do you want to select both tables when @table is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

You have two solution about value @table.

You can consider @table = NULL about selection of both tables, or you can consider @table = value (for example 3 as sum of 1 and 2),
so your query becomes:

If you choose @table = NULL:

```
Declare @table = NULL

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE <stuff>
AND (@Table = 1 OR @table IS NULL)

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Table2
WHERE <stuff>
AND (@Table = 2 OR @table IS NULL)
```

If you choose @Table = value (for example 3)

```
Declare @table = 3

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE <stuff>
AND (@Table = 1 OR @table = 3)

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Table2
WHERE <stuff>
AND (@Table = 2 OR @table = 3)
```

Comment: This answer is probably how I would've done it. One cases where it selects from table1, one for table2, and a third case for selecting from both. Straight forward and easily maintainable.

Comment: @LudvigRydahl: Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't performance hurt in your query? I'd prefer answer by @MayowaO even though it's not that pretty.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas: You can accept what you want ;) In this way you can change only the value of Table variable, in that answer you must maintanance three queries

Comment: @JoeTaras I'm not OP. I'm just genuinely interested :)

Comment: I prefer this one. Thanks.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas: Sorry, I've check after you are not OP ;) All feedback are very appreciated... ALWAYS! Have a nice day my dear

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas well it could hit performance, but not very noticeable unless the queries get really (and then I mean reaaaally)  large.  Hell I've ran threeway queries of this kind on very large tables without any problem. And it has a lot to do with order of query execution. Since the `where` is executed before the `select`, I imagine the query being entirely disposed because of `2 not in (1,3)`, and therefore giving almost no performance impact. But hey, I could be wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IF...ELSE statements to achieve this as shown below.
I am assuming you want to use @table to control what the script should do.

```
Declare @table = 1

IF @table = 1 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1  
    WHERE <stuff>
END

ELSE IF @table = 2
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Table2
    WHERE <stuff>
END

ELSE IF @table = 3 /* OR @table IN (1,2) --depends on how you want to handle this*/
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    WHERE <stuff>

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *
    FROM Table2
    WHERE <stuff>
END
```

The script will stop as soon as the condition is satisfied.
For example IF @Table = 2, only the following sections of script will run:

```
ELSE IF @table = 2
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Table2
    WHERE <stuff>
END
```

Answer (score -3):

Hope this helps:

```
SELECT maker, Product.model AS model_1, PC.model AS model_2, price
FROM Product INNER JOIN PC ON PC.model = Product.model
ORDER BY maker, PC.model;
```

Comment: This query won't return anything if table Product is empty.