# How to change table name in from clause based on a parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a select statement, in from clause, table name changes depending on a parameter.
I tried:

```
from
IIf(@prmdataVal ='Dummy', tbl1, tbl2) T1
```

It's showing an error. How to do this?

Comment: Did you already try to use dynamic SQL? You can't change the from part of a query except in dynamic SQL...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable). Or (if it's always exactly those two tables) [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7533539/4137916).

Comment: This kind of pattern generally indicates a database modelling issue

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following:

```
DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max);
SELECT @stmt = 'SELECT * FROM ' + CASE WHEN @prmdataVal = 'Dummy' THEN 'tbl1' ELSE 'tbl2' END
EXEC @stmt
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a variable for table name and then calling it in the from clause of dynamic SQL, worked.

```
Declare @TblName AS SYSNAME = CASE WHEN @prmdataVal='Dummy' THEN 'tbl1'
ELSE 'tbl2' end
```

and then calling it in the dynamic sql:

```
from '+@TblName +' as T1...
```